# We currently do not support linking to an AdWords account managed through AdWords My Client Center

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to use admob ads for the first time in android application.
My first step was login via their page:
https://www.admob.com/home/login/login

I'm trying to use my existing google account beacase this is one of possible options.
Since I'm from Croatia, I use this link:
https://apps.admob.com/admob/signup

After sign in there is red error message saying:

> We currently do not support linking to an AdWords account managed through AdWords My Client Center

and page says: **Sign in with another Google account.**

I don't want to use another google account and I never used AdWords (no account there).
Does anybody has solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. This is how I solved it:

1. Log in to your Adwords account, click in the help link and open the chat.
2. Explain your problem and ask for your Adwords account to be converted to a regular Adwords account.
3. Wait for the phone call from Google asking for permission for the change.

They said I then had to wait 24h, but it was not needed. I clicked just a couple of seconds after the change and it went trough.